# Passing an integer variable from api controller to Mvc Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web api controller and a mvc controller.  I am calling the web api controller from the mvc controller. I want the api controller to pass an integer variable to the mvc controller.

**Here is my MVC Controller**

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
            public ActionResult CreateStudent(StudentViewModel student)
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:39673/api/student");
                    var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<StudentViewModel>("student", student);
                    postTask.Wait();    

                    var result = postTask.Result;
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return Redirect("Index"); ;
                    }
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");

                return View(student);
            }
```

**Here is my api controller**(sid is the integer variable which i need to be passed to the above MVC controller)

```
    public IHttpActionResult PostStudent(StudentViewModel student)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return BadRequest("Invalid data.");

                using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
                {
                    ctx.Students.Add(new Student()
                    {
                        Name = student.Name,
                        MobileNO = student.MobileNO
                    });

                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    int sid = ctx.Students.Max(item => item.StudentID);
                }           
                return Ok();
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just return OK(sid); from web api.

And read it in the MVC controller as below.

```
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    int yourStudentIDFromAPI = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<int>();
}
```

Comment: I tried it. but i don't know how to retrieve sid in mvc controller.

Comment: Please try the revised ans above.. One more observation, why you need to call the web api from c# code? Cannot we call it from the client browser itself? and Handle the response..